# What is an equivalent in rxjs6 of Promise.resolve

Tags: observable, es6-promise, web-sql, rxjs6

I'm trying to resolve after an async call to the websql api.
For now I'm returning a Promise and it's working. however, for some reasons of design,I would like to do it with rxjs6 observables.
Do you know how to have the same behavior with rxjs ?

Please take in account that `tx.executeSql` and `websqlDatabase.transaction` return void and I don't have access to the code of these functions.

Thanks in advance

```js
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.websqlDatabase.transaction(tx => {
          tx.executeSql(statement, params, (transaction, results) => {
            resolve(results);
          }, (transaction, error) => {
            reject(error);
          });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new observable, as you do with a promise, and then call `observable.next(<var>)` to pipe the result to the subscribed object. Ensure you also call `observable.complete()` to notify the observable that the pipe can be closed.

This code is the rxjs equivalent to the above code:

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const observable = new Observable(observer => {
    this.websqlDatabase.transaction(tx => {
        tx.executeSql(statement, params, (transaction, results) => {
            observable.next(results);
            observer.complete();
        }, (transaction, error) => {
            observable.error(error);
        });
     });
});

observable.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```